# Ensure that parsedatetime does not parse an invalid date/time string

Tags: python, parsing, date, time

Using the parsedatetime library by Bear on Python 2.7 over Ubuntu 12.04.  When passing in a string that contains characters but no valid date (or time) sometimes the parse() function returns a valid date/time.

After filing Issue 48, it looks like parsedatetime really doesn't want a string that doesn't have a date/time in it.

So, thoughts on a pre-processor to determine a Boolean value to whether or not the string contains a valid date?

reference links:
https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/
https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/issues/detail?id=48

Note: in Issue 48 I call out parseDateText() inappropriately.  I have confirmed the same operation exists with parse().

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Example Code.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import parsedatetime as pdt
>>> c = pdt.Constants()
>>> c.BirthdayEpoc = 80
>>> p = pdt.Calendar(c)
>>> print p.parse("Mary had a little lamb.")
((2014, 3, 1, 20, 53, 56, 6, 69, 1), 1)
>>> print p.parse("foo bar")
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=20, tm_min=54, tm_sec=6, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=69, tm_isdst=1), 0)
>>> print p.parse("March 12th, 2013")
((2013, 3, 12, 20, 54, 34, 6, 69, 1), 1)
>>>
```

Comment: Provide a complete minimal example that demonstrates the issue. You probably want to file another issue that uses `parse()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As J.F. mentioned, the proper call to use is the parse() method.  The parse method also has the value of returning a tuple that contains two items: one is the date/time value determined and the other is a flag to show if any date/time value was found...

Here is the breakdown of the returned flag value:

- 0 = not parsed at all
- 1 = parsed as a date
- 2 = parsed as a time
- 3 = parsed as a datetime

If your getting anything other than a 0 from your tests then you have found a bug :/